# Python : 3D graph with 4 arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, graph, 3d

I tried to make a 3D graph in Python with four arrays : three for the position x, y, z and the last one is a multidimensionnal array that gives the potential at all the considered points. I want to illustrate the magnitude of the potential according to the position. It's like the contour lines in 2D.

Could you help me? All I found is how to make 3D graphs with points or with only three arrays.

Thank you!

Comment: Please, post the code of your try

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code! In the x, y and z axis, the position varies from 0 to 10 by bond of 0.2.

x = y = z = []

for i in range(0, 51):

```
x.append(i/5)
```

potential is a matrix of 51 x 51 x 51.

v = potential

fig = figure()

ax = Axes3D(fig)

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

For the graph, I tried many things like :

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, v)  **or**

ax.contourf(x, y, z, v)

In both cases, I have a error : z has to be in 2D. And I'm not even sure that both functions could take a fourth argument!